# populate drop down list from array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, drop-down-menu

I have a country list that I have called in - and have parsed into the following format:

```
{"Countries"=>[{"Name"=>"ABKHAZIA", "IsoCode"=>"AB", "HasTown"=>"I"}, {"Name"=>"ANGUILLA", "IsoCode"=>"AI", "HasTown"=>"I"}, {"Name"=>"ANTIGUA", "IsoCode"=>"AG", "HasTown"=>"I"}, .... {"Name"=>"ZIMBABWE", "IsoCode"=>"ZW", "HasTown"=>"I"}]}
```

I want to populate a drop down list with this data.  Code I am using to create the drop down box is:

```
def country_selection_input options = {}
options.reverse_merge!(
  :attribute => :country_iso,
  :collection => transaction_form.get_countries,
  :input_html => {},
  :prompt => 'please select',
  :label => 'To Where'
)
```

This gives me a  drop down box with a please select prompt and a list that consists of only the one word: Countries.

The data is there - but I am not sure how to get it into the drop down list - and am sure I am missing something simple. 
I have tried

```
:label_method => :Name,
```

but get an error message of

```
undefined method `Name' for #<Array:0x007fc385cecbb0>
```

This will probably turn into a menu as I want to take action based on the country selected - but - this is the first step - getting the list to work.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of needed dropdown box? Which values do you expect to have there? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being

```
def country_selection_input options = {}
countries = transaction_form.get_countries()[:Countries]
options.reverse_merge!(
  :attribute => :country_iso,
  :collection => countries,
  :label_method => :Name,
  :value_method => :IsoCode,
  :input_html => {},
  :prompt => 'please select',
  :label => 'To Where'
)

call_input_from_args_hash options
```

end